# Spreading out super thin pan cake batter

Tags: pancakes

I am using store bought pan cake mix to make pancakes, and one problem I have is that the batter is super thin after prepping. This makes it difficult to pour it onto the skillet when cooking. When I try, it's quite inconsistent the size of my pancakes, and sometimes by mistake I end up filling the pan.

Any tips to improve my pancake batter pouring skills?

Comment: What do you mean by "pancakes" - American style thick pancakes, or something thinner like crêpes?

Comment: Have you checked the preparation? Store-bought mixed shouldn’t be super thin for American style and for the other kind you’d be filling the entire pan anyway?

Comment: It's french pancakes @rumtscho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ladle.

See [Best Ladles for Pancakes – Essential Guide](https://foodsguy.com/best-ladles-for-pancakes/) - which, to be honest, is more a way of giving you affiliate links to ladles than helping you choose, but there's some worth in the article.

Really, all you need is one the right size to make your idea of a standard pancake; then you get the same amount every time.

This one is just a shopping listing, but it does tell you the size Delia Smith uses in her cookery school, for pancakes -  35ml - https://www.deliaonline.com/equipment/pancake-ladle

Comment: Or a measuring cup - my ready-made mix says slightly less than 1/4 cup. Or an ice cream scoop, I use mine mostly for batter.

Comment: true - I don't actually have any real measuring cups that small. I have 500ml to 2l, nothing smaller. My one & only ladle serves me for many functions, including some slight guesswork when I don't need a full ladle. I get by ;)) A ladle can also do the spreading part too.

Answer (score 0):

There is some technique to making crepes or very thin pancakes.  It starts with pouring the correct amount (usually less than you think). Then, if I am not misunderstanding, I think you may need a crepe spreading tool to help make the batter even across the pan. Something like this (there are slightly different versions, but same idea):

[image]